# Invoke-SqlCmd generates an exception in foreach loop?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am running 2 different sql query one after the other to get the details from database using Invoke-Sqlcmd but getting an exception.

> The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing methods, and they can only be called from within the same thread. Validate that the cmdlet makes these calls correctly

Script:

```
$ok = "true"
$serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM sys.server_audits WHERE name = 'Login'"
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_audit_status WHERE name = 'Login' AND status_desc = 'STARTED'"

try
{
    Write-Host "Getting running Sql Server Instance (online)"
    $sqlInstances = (Get-Service -Name MSSQL$* | Where-Object { $_.status -eq "Running" }).Name

    $sqlInstancesCount = $sqlInstances.Count
    Write-Host $eventID "$sqlInstancesCount Sql Server Instance found"

    if($sqlInstancesCount)
    {
        foreach($item in $sqlInstances)
        {
            $count = 0
            $instanceName = $item -replace "MSSQL\$", ""
            $sqlInstanceFullname = Join-Path -Path $serverName -ChildPath "\" | Join-Path -ChildPath $instanceName
            Write-Host "Sql Server instance fullname - $sqlInstanceFullname"

            while($count -lt 3)
            {
                Write-Host "Clear existing connection."
                [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools()
                
                Write-Host "Executing query - $query1"
                $result1 = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query1 -ServerInstance $sqlInstanceFullname)

                Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

                Write-Host "Clear existing connection."
                [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools()
                
                Write-Host "Executing query - $query2"
                $result2 = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query2 -ServerInstance $sqlInstanceFullname)

                if($null -eq $result1)
                {
                    $message = "$serverName - The SQL Server [Login] does not exist."
                    $ok = "false"
                    $count = $count + 1
                }
                elseif($null -eq $result2)
                {
                    $message = "$serverName - The SQL Server [Login] is disabled."
                    $ok = "false"
                    $count = $count + 1
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = "SQL Login is enabled and running."
                    $count = 3
                    $ok = "true"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $ok = "false"
        throw "$serverName - SQL Server Instances might be offline or not exist!"
    }
}
catch
{
    throw $_
}
```

I have tried enclosing Invoke-Sqlcmd in brackets but still getting same exception so is there a way to remove existing thread or close the connection before executing another query.

Comment: Please show _the full error message_, including the call site (where the exception was thrown)

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are connecting to each instance.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and check log files in the explorer under Management which will give more details on error.  You should see the script connecting to the server/instance.  If you do not see the connection than you need to add the connection open in the script.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen exception thrown while executing 2nd query.

Comment: @jdweng it's connection and getting result for the 1st query while trying to execute 2nd query it's throwing exception.

Comment: This is a powershell error.  Add the details of your powershell environment an Sql Server module version.

Comment: You are doing three queries on each instance.  You only need to clear the pool for each instance (not each query).  So you can have one clear pool before the while loop.  Is it failing one of the 3 queries for an first instance or may be it is failing for a different instance.